# LED Chaser using counting IC

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, counter

**Total** beginner here,

I'm trying to build an "LED Chaser" circuit using an IC [(CD4022BE)](https://produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/150000-174999/172774-da-01-en-C_MOS_IC_CD_4022_BE_DIP16_TID.pdf) that counts to eight (from zero to seven, and then it wraps around and goes back to zero).

Before trying to fit all eight LEDs onto a breadboard, I figured I would try it with two LEDs first. The datasheet labels the eight relevant outputs as "0" through "7", so my LED "0" is connected to pin 2, and my LED "1" is connected to pin 1. The idea was that I start at "0", then send in one CLOCK pulse to jump to "1". Then, since I have only two LEDs connected, I would have to send in seven more CLOCK pulses before the cycle repeats and my LED "0" lights up again.

I came up with the following circuit:
[image: hmm]

I'm powering the whole thing with 9 Volts, just because it seems convenient.
I've tried to implement this circuit on my breadboard but I'm getting behavior I don't understand and didn't expect (Hint, I have no idea what I'm doing). When I connect my battery, my LED "0" lights up as expected, but when I connect a jumper wire from +9V to pin 14 (CLOCK), nothing happens (I was expecting it to turn off LED "0" and turn on LED "1").

Across the terminals of my battery I measured 8.79V (OK). I measured 8.79V across VDD and VSS (Don't know if it's supposed to do that. I guess ICs don't have voltage drop? Does that sentence even make sense?). I measured 2V across LED "0". To my surprise, I measured 4V across LED "1" (Oops), and finally, I measured 4.04V across the potentiometer.

I don't really understand where these numbers are coming from. I have absolutely no intuition when it comes to electronics, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you "connect a jumper wire..." it might bounce the contact for like tens or hundreds of times. To make this work you will need some kind of debouncing circuit. And anyway, if I understand correctly what "LED chaser" is, then you need a shift register and not a counter.

Comment: "I guess ICs don't have voltage drop?" -> You're right, that does not make sense. What you _measured_ there is the voltage drop across the IC; what _doesn't_ have voltage drop in this case is the wires between the battery and the IC (they actually do, but it's tiny)

Comment: @EugeneSh. This particular type of counter will work for this, as it's a decoded counter; it outputs with a one-of-eight encoding. It's an octal version of the classic 4017.

Comment: @Hearth - Thanks for that. Right, so the IC is dropping 8.79V (somehow, my brain thought there was no voltage drop because that number was the same as the voltage I measured across the battery).

Comment: It's not all that useful to think of it in terms of voltage drop, though. Don't worry too much about that, just think of it as the power supply.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for the input. I've heard of debouncing circuits. However, if the problem I'm experiencing really is due to bouncing, wouldn't my LEDs at least sometimes turn on and off, rapidly at least? The way things are now, anytime I send a CLOCK pulse, nothing happens (LED "0" stays on).

Comment: @user10987432 Well, if you measured 4V across one of the LEDs, you've either connected it backwards or fried it, or both. So you wouldn't expect that one to flicker at all. Either way, contact bounce is so rapid that it wouldn't be visible.

Comment: @Hearth - Ah, that makes sense. Theoretically, if I swap the fried LED with a new one, and I implement a debouncing circuit, do you see any other obvious flaws? Also, I realize you said that when measuring 8.79V across VDD and VSS, it's not useful to think about it in terms of voltage drop - but just to satisfy my curiosity, does that mean those 8.79V are being dissipated as heat, somewhere on the IC? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user10987432 No, it does not mean it's being dissipated as heat. There will only be any heat when there is both voltage and current, and the energy isn't being used for something other than heat.

Comment: All CMOS inputs have to be tied to V+ or GND - either directly or via a pull-up / pull-down resistor. You can't leave them floating as shown in your diagram. 10k to 100k would be fine.

Comment: @Transistor - Good to know. When you say CMOS inputs, in my case you are referring to RESET, CLOCK and INHIBIT, yes?